# jQuery: set value of text field from text label of select menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set the value of a text field from the *text* (not the value) of a `<select>`, and I can't get it to work.

```
$('.prices_for_' + <%= d.id %>).change(function() {
  $('#order_quantity').text($(this).text())
  $('.price_display').text('$' + $(this).val() + '.00')
});
```

The second line works, the first doesn't. Any ideas?

Comment: input fields don't have text.. they have value... can you tell us what are you expecting from line 1

Comment: Post your html code related to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off the title where you said you want to set it from the text of the select menu - you could use an attribute selector to `.find` the `option` with the value that was selected, and then call `.text()` on it:

```
$('.prices_for_' + <%= d.id %>).change(function() {
    var text = $(this).find('option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').text();
    $('#order_quantity').text(text);
    $('.price_display').text('$' + $(this).val() + '.00')
});
```